# Forced Logout in .Net Core API using OpenId Connect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

Basically, we remove the Token from client side when user clicks on Logout.

Now, the problem is, if user opens 2 different tabs and in one tab clicked on Logout, which will delete the Token and Logged out. Perfectly fine. But in another tab, the Token is still present. If user does some functionality then the same Token will successfully validated by server and return the response which is very bad and we want to restrict that.

So how can we do Forced Logout from Server as well ?
Here, is what we are using,

I am using OpenIdDict for Login purpose in my .Net Core 6 Api project. I have referred [OpenIdDict official repository](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples)

Basically, after successfully Login, our API returns a Token to front-end, so that our API validate the same user to grant access for other API end point. This is fine.

Now, let me give few more details about our User management. Once a new user registered in our portal, basically using a front-end(which is an Angular application), it calls our .Net core API. Our .Net Core API doesn't save user details to our database. What it does, our register API internally calls an external API which will eventually save the user details in there database. For login also, our .Net core API calls external API to validate there side.

> That means our .Net Core API is just a wrapper to the main API. Now,
> we have added OpenIdConnect to .Net Core API (which is just a
> wrapper). It's fine till this.

Can someone help, how can I forcefully logout or expiry/delete the Token from serverside ?

Here is some code from my program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    })
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            // Enable the token endpoint.options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/Connect/Token").SetLogoutEndpointUris("/Connect/Logout");
            options.AllowPasswordFlow()
                   .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
            options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
            options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                   .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
            options.UseAspNetCore()
                   .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough().
                   EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough().DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();
            
        })
```

Our Logout method:

```
[HttpPost("~/Connect/Logout"), Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    return SignOut(
        authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        properties: new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:****/Connect/Token"
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logout method should not return anything, a more proper logout method should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults );

    //Important, this method should never return anything.
}
```

Also, it is good to sign out from both handlers.

Comment: Hi @Tore Nestenius, Thanks for your comment, however I am getting exception `Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie(\"Cookies\",...)?. No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect'.`

Comment: I use this `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);' No error. But still I am able to call and get value from all the API. It should through 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: First of all I recommend that you separate the client and OpenIddict and place them in separate services, as troubleshooting and reasoning about the system is sooo much harder when you mix them together. Yes ,  you should use OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults instead of OpenIdConnectDefaults., I updated my answer.

Comment: Secondly, you have tree things to disable when you signout, 1, the session with your client (AddCookie...), the session with OpenIdDict), and the tokens. Which of these are handled and which is not properly signed out?